# What dose the terminology “majorize” mean？

Tags: terminology, von-neumann-algebras, projection

A projection in a von Neumann algebra $A$ is central if it commutes 
with every element of $A$.

We say that $A$ is Type I if every non-zero central projection in $A$ 
**majorizes** a non-zero abelian projection in $A$. 
We say that A is Type II if it has no non-zero abelian projections and 
every non-zero central projection **majorizes** a non-zero finite projection.

What dose the terminology “majorize” mean？If $\operatorname{ran}p\subset \operatorname{ran}q$, can we say $p$ is majorized by $q$? where $p$ and $q$ are projections in $A$.

Answer (score 1):

“$p$ majorizes $q$” is simply a way to pronounce $p \leq q$.  ($p \leq q$ iff $q-p = c^*c$ for some c.  If represented on some Hilbert space $H$, this is equivalent to $\langle p x,x\rangle \leq \langle q x,x \rangle$ for every vector $x \in H$.)

Comment: I would do it the other way around,  "$p$ majorizes $q$" means $p \ge q$.